# Replacing user text in post contents when rendered

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the MOST correct way according to WP ideology to replace user text in the post content?

Example: I want to replace `[b] User Text[/b]` To `<strong> User text</strong>` when text rendered in the browser

Do I need filter? 
Do I need Short code API? Or it is perfectly fine to use PHP text replacing functions?

A small code sample will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), then your code for the **functions.php** would look something like this:

```
<?php
function shortcode_b_replace($atts, $content = null) {
    return '<strong>'.$content.'</strong>';
}
add_shortcode("b", "shortcode_b_replace");
?>
```

Comment: sure. thats why the functions.php is for ;) Read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File